# PHP echo array value after while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop, echo

How can I echo out value after the while loop. If I do the echo in below code its says Undefined index.

```
$sql_cast = "SELECT *
            FROM
              title_cast
              INNER JOIN title ON (title_cast.id_title = title.id)
              INNER JOIN `cast` ON (title_cast.id_cast = `cast`.id)
            WHERE
              title_cast.id_title = '1'";
$result_cast = mysql_query($sql_cast) or die('log error with' .mysql_error());
$cast = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_cast)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $img = $row['photo_localurl'];
                $poster = str_replace("./", "lib/", $img);

                $cast[] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'img' => $poster);
                //$cast[] = $row;
                }
                //var_dump($cast);
                echo $cast['id'] . " " . $cast['name'] . " " . $cast['poster']."<br />";
```

Comment: Try var_dump($row) first in the while loop. Also, I would expect `while( ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_cast)) !== FALSE ) {` or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the while loop, you set the cast array content using `$cast[]` syntax. This will create a numerical index, starting at 0, then 1 and so on, so you're creating an array that looks like this:

```
$cast = array(
    0 => array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'img' => $poster),
    1 => array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'img' => $poster)
);
```

You need to include the numerical key of the array that you want to echo. For example, if you want to echo the first row:

```
echo $cast[0]['id']; // Echo the id of the first result
```

If you want to echo ALL of the rows, use `foreach`:

```
foreach($cast as $row) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do:

```
$cast = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'img' => $poster);
                //$cast[] = $row;
                }
                //var_dump($cast);
echo $cast['id'] . " " . $cast['name'] . " " . $cast['poster']."<br />";
```

because if you use **$cast[]**, it will append the new array to your array..

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are pushing a new array in $cast at each index..

So you should echo like this..

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_cast)) {
      $id = $row['id'];
      $name = $row['name'];
      $img = $row['photo_localurl'];
      $poster = str_replace("./", "lib/", $img);

      $cast[] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'img' => $poster);
      //$cast[] = $row;

      //var_dump($cast);
      echo $cast[$i]['id'] . " " . $cast[$i]['name'] . " " . $cast[$i]['poster']."<br />";
      $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($cast[0]); or you can use $cast[0]['id'] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_cast)) {
      $id = $row['id'];
      $name = $row['name'];
      $img = $row['photo_localurl'];
      $poster = str_replace("./", "lib/", $img);

      $cast[] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'img' => $poster);
}

foreach($cast as $rows) {
    echo $rows['id']." ".$rows['name']." ".$rows['img']."<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code, First is that $cast[] is a two-dimensional array so it contains arrays at each of its index, so you must use

```
$cast[$i]['id']
```

Where i will be the counter variable that will iterate through all the indexes. Secondly change

```
$cast['poster']
```

to

```
$cast['img']
```

Hope this helps.